# T-SQL Query against previous queries results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a hard time searching the internet for this, so thought I would ask the T-SQL question here.  I have a table called CUST.  CUST contains customer entrydate, name, company, address, email, among other things.  I wrote a simple query to find new customers based off entrydate;

```
Select * from CUST WHERE ENTRYDATE between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-30'
```

This works great, except I found a problem.  When our webstore creates new orders, if the customer details don't match EXACTLY, a new customer is created.  That being the case, I want to take my original results, and trim the results set if I have more than one occurrence of cust.firstname + cust.lastname + cust.company.  I can write these in individual queries, just unsure how to do this in a single sql script.

I thought about doing a join on name back to the table, and while the join doesn't error, I don't know how to count the occurrences, I was thinking of counting customer numbers.

My join looks like this (stripped out the group by and column selection to make it easier to read;

```
from CUST
    Right Outer Join 
    (
    select *
    from CUST 
    WHERE ENTRYDATE between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-30'
            AND LTRIM(RTRIM(Firstname + Lastname + Company)) <> ''
    Group By *     
    ) as newcs

    on LTRIM(RTRIM(CUST.Firstname + CUST.Lastname + CUST.Company)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(newcs.Firstname + newcs.Lastname + newcs.Company))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What are you using for the customer login? If you use an email address you can stop the system from make new accounts for the same customer.

Comment: Sorry, using SQL-Server 2003.  I have no control over the webstore, or the customer order system (the other place customers are created).  I do have access to the database though.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2003.  Do you mean 2008?  2005? 2000?

Comment: Without a CustomerID (primary key) have no way to establish which duplicates are valid and which are not.

Comment: I don't think Name + Company is unique enough to merge these records, what about people that leave company blank?

Comment: we aren't merging records.  This is a report that is dumped automatically to the users shared folder.  Basically if the name exists more than once its not a new customer and shouldn't be listed in my report.  In the final query I used based off of Diana's answer below, I ended up doing name + zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct records in the current time period that were not entered prior to this reporting period:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.*
FROM @CUST c1
WHERE c1.ENTRYDATE BETWEEN '2012-08-01' AND '2012-08-30'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM @CUST c2 
    WHERE c2.ENTRYDATE < '2012-08-01'
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(c1.Firstname + c1.Lastname + c1.Company)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(c2.Firstname + c2.Lastname + c2.Company))
)
```

Comment: Thanks Diana, this did the trick.  Will save my customer service person hours of labor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to delete the duplicate records, you can use the following script:

```
DELETE FROM Customer
WHERE PKCol IN 
(    
    SELECT PK_Column FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, Company ORDER BY EntryDate) AS RN, PK_Column
        FROM Customers
    ) A
    WHERE A.RN > 1 
)
```

Comment: Not trying to delete, just trying to create a report that accurately dumps a list of new users for my customer service staff.

Answer (score 0):

This query results only **newest** customers with distinct (trimmed) FirstName+LastName+Company

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Company,EntryDate FROM(
    SELECT *, R=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EntryDate DESC) FROM(
        SELECT FirstName,LastName,Company , EntryDate, ID= LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(LastName)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(Company))
         FROM CUST
        WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-30'
        ) AS a
    ) AS b
WHERE R=1
```

If you need to take oldest ones, remove the `DESC` part after `ORDER BY` Clause

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I will start investigating and report back which ones work!